# Increase the size of the WebSQL quota in a WebView

Tags: android, webview, web-sql, quota

In a normal Android web app the maximum size for a WebSQL database is normally around 8MB. In a hybrid web app I am making I would like to increase this limit. How would I go about doing that?

It seems that [WebStorage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebStorage.html) might have something to do with it, but the only method I can see there that seems to set the size, `setQuotaForOrigin`,  is marked *deprecated*.

Sample code (that is not deprecated) is welcome :)

Comment: I'm looking for the exact opposite solution. iOS7 has a "bug" that throws a security exception when you try to exceed the size limit. So I need to downsize my DB to avoid this. I'll post whatever I find on that regard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quota for a web app seems to differ from that of a hybrid app (as in something running within a view). Regardless, by implementing the following in your `android.app.Activity` subclass you will double the quota until it finally stops at approximately 48MB.

```
@Override
public void onExceededDatabaseQuota(String url, String databaseIdentifier, long currentQuota, long estimatedSize, long totalUsedQuota, WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater) {
    quotaUpdater.updateQuota(estimatedSize * 2);
}
```

The user will not be asked to interact when this happens.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at this other question on [how to increase quota limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895408/how-can-i-increase-the-quota-limit-of-localstorage-in-android-webview?rq=1).

Looks like changing the size is only a problem for users that already have a local DB created, this is because there is no way to change the size of the DB when running [upgrade scripts for versioning](http://blog.maxaller.name/2010/03/html5-web-sql-database-intro-to-versioning-and-migrations/). That said, you just only need to change the size in the initialization script (code in JavaScript):

```
var size = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // changed from 5 to 10MB
var db = openDatabase("oversized_db", "v1.1", "Ten MB DB", size);
```

Take into account that this will only affect new users. All users that have previously created a DB with a different size need to clear their cache (you have controll of the cache on a webView so its not that bad) but all previous data would be lost (unless you manually migrate it to the new DB with native code).
In my case I have to do the same but decreasing the size. That would take care of the issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is something else. this won't affect the quota set by the Android OS. this only sets the size of the existing database. and I have yet to see that actually do _anything_. in all tests I have done that size is just baloney. I can set a size of 10 byte and I can still fill it up to the quota is exceeded. I will add an answer now with more info.

Comment: This is how its done for a regular web app. I'm not sure how you are doing it. But limits are usualy set by the browser, this is the way to attempt to create a DB of a set size.

Comment: I know that is the way it is done for a regular web app. I am just saying that the size argument does _nothing_. I should do the expected thing - set the size, but it seems to be ignored by most browsers. the real max size is set by the browser/view.

Comment: That is precisely how it works. You can start with a DB size of 0 and let it "grow" to the space it requires. Size is only used in some OS/Browsers to verify for remaining quota, it is even called "suggested size" in some of iOS Safari documentation. So, as you say it doesn't set a size.