# Alternative to deprecated onExceededDatabaseQuota()

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, android-webview, quota

My app is executing some Javascript code in a WebView which creates a database. In some situations when the database grows past a certain size I am getting this Javascript error:

> there was not enough remaining storage space, or the storage quota was reached and the user declined to allow more space

The [historical workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237112/increase-the-size-of-the-websql-quota-in-a-webview) for this has been to override [`WebChromeClient.onExceededDatabaseQuota()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onExceededDatabaseQuota(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20android.webkit.WebStorage.QuotaUpdater)) which allows the native app code to increase the quota as needed. This has been deprecated since API level 19, though, and is no longer called. The Javadoc says:

> WebView now uses the HTML5 / JavaScript Quota Management API.

Is this new Quota Management API accessible to my Android app code? Is there an alternative way for me to tell my WebView to increase the storage quota?

Comment: As per android document `WebView now uses the HTML5 / JavaScript Quota Management API`. For Quota Management API check https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/11/Quota-Management-API-Fast-Facts?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out there was actually insufficient space left on the emulator's internal storage. After I edited the AVD to give it more space, the error disappeared.